# I get an 'identifier not found' error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, identifier

This is my first attempt to create a basic list (i need this at school) and i get a strange error.

This is the script:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

struct nod
{
    int info;
    nod *leg;
};

int n, info;
nod *v;
void main()
{
    ....
    addToList(v, info); //I get the error here
    showList(v); //and here
}

void addToList(nod*& v, int info)
{
    nod *c = new nod;
    c->info=info;
    c->leg=v;
    v=c;
}

void showList(nod* v)
{
    nod *c = v;
    while(c)
    {
        cout<<c->info<<" ";
        c=c->leg;
    }
}
```

The exact error is:
error C3861: 'addToList': identifier not found

I dont know why I get this... sorry if it is a stupid question but i am very new at this. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put a forward declaration to use a method before it's implementation. Put this before main :

```
void addToList(nod*& v, int info);
```

In C/C++ a method should be used only after it's declaration. To allow recursive call between different methods you can use [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) in order to allow the use of a function/method that will be forward implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers must be declared before they are used. Move your declaration and definition of `addToList` earlier in the text file.

Thus:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;

struct nod
{
    int info;
    nod *leg;
};

int n, info;
nod *v;

void addToList(nod*& v, int info)
{
    nod *c = new nod;
    c->info=info;
    c->leg=v;
    v=c;
}

void showList(nod* v)
{
    nod *c = v;
    while(c)
    {
        cout<<c->info<<" ";
        c=c->leg;
    }
}


void main()
{
    ....
    addToList(v, info); //No more error here
    showList(v); //and here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring addToList above main:

`void addToList(nod*& v, int info);`

Similarly for showList. The compiler needs to see a declaration of the function before it can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the declarations of `showList()` and `addToList()` before `main()`.